# How do i get the a value from Decoder type in Elm

Tags: json, elm

I'm currently trying to update an old project someone else has made from 0.18.

I have the types Msg and Mouse

```
type Msg =
SelectElement Int
| ApplyTool (Maybe Int) Mouse

type alias Mouse =
  {
    x: Int
    , y: Int
  }
```

The problem is that i'm using Json.Decode to do some mapping and therefor end up with value with type : `Decoder Msg`

Is there a easy way to get just the value from Msg?

Answer (score 2):

A `Decoder` doesn't hold a value, it knows how to produce a value from JSON input (or fail if the JSON isn't in the right format).

If you're trying to adjust the value being decoded, you can use [`Json.Decode.map`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/json/latest/Json-Decode#map) or [`Json.Decode.andThen`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/json/latest/Json-Decode#andThen). Maybe it could look something like this:

```
mouseDecoder =
    Json.Decode.map2 (\x y -> Mouse x y)
        (Json.Decode.field "pageX" Json.Decode.int)
        (Json.Decode.field "pageY" Json.Decode.int)

msgDecoder =
    mouseDecoder
        |> Json.Decode.map (\mouse -> ApplyTool Nothing mouse)
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot! It also made me realise that what I am actually looking for is to use the value that the decoder knows how to produce. In this case the mouseDecoder will return a JSON.Decoder Mouse type, but I'm actually after the Mouse type and use it later.

Comment: In this scenario, I would imagine that you're passing the decoder to [`Html.Events.on`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/latest/Html-Events#on), which will produce that message in response to an HTML event (or, alternatively, [`Browser.Events.onMouseMove`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser-Events#onMouseMove), which produces the message in response to that global browser event).